# Detached thread won't exit although it runs pthread_exit?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore, pthread-exit

I have been dealing with a problem in a thread pool for some days now. I tried all types of different things but I can't seem to solve the issue. I have made a simple version that reproduces the problem.

**Code:**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h> 


struct bsem_t bsem;
pthread_t threads[2];


/* Binary semaphore */
typedef struct bsem_t {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t   cond;
    int v;
} bsem_t;

void bsem_post(bsem_t *bsem) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bsem->mutex);
    bsem->v = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&bsem->cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bsem->mutex);
}

void bsem_wait(bsem_t *bsem) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bsem->mutex);
    while (bsem->v != 1) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&bsem->cond, &bsem->mutex);
    }
    bsem->v = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bsem->mutex);
}


/* Being called by each thread on SIGUSR1 */
void thread_exit(){
    printf("%u: pthread_exit()\n", (int)pthread_self());
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


/* Startpoint for each thread */
void thread_do(){

    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = thread_exit;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL);

    while(1){
        bsem_wait(&bsem); // Each thread is blocked here
        puts("Passed semaphore");
    }

}


/* Main */
int main(){

    bsem.v = 0;

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, (void *)thread_do, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, (void *)thread_do, NULL);
    pthread_detach(threads[0]);
    pthread_detach(threads[1]);
    puts("Created threads");

    sleep(2);

    pthread_kill(threads[0], SIGUSR1);
    pthread_kill(threads[1], SIGUSR1);

    puts("Killed threads");

    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

What the code does, is create two threads. Both threads wait on a binary semaphore (*bsem_wait*). Then while they are waiting I send a `SIGUSR1` signal to both resulting on `pthread_exit()` being executed on each thread. On my terminal it shows that everything goes as planned..

**Output:**

```
Created threads
Killed threads
2695145216: pthread_exit()
2686752512: pthread_exit()
```

**The problem**

Although the output seems correct, using `pstree` shows that only one of two threads die. The other thread stays alive until the whole program exits. Why is this?

---

**Update**

Replacing my custom binary semaphore with a normal semaphore seems to solve this for no apparent reason..

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <semaphore.h> 

sem_t sem;
pthread_t threads[2];


/* Caller thread will exit */
void thread_exit(){
    printf("%u: pthread_exit()\n", (int)pthread_self());
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


/* Startpoint for each thread */
void* thread_do(){

    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = thread_exit;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL);

    while(1){
        sem_wait(&sem); // Each thread is blocked here
        puts("Passed semaphore");
    }

}


/* Main */
int main(){

    sem_init(&sem, 0, 0); // Normal semaphore

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, thread_do, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, thread_do, NULL);
    pthread_detach(threads[0]);
    pthread_detach(threads[1]);
    puts("Created threads in pool");

    sleep(2);

    //PROBLEM
    pthread_kill(threads[0], SIGUSR1);
    pthread_kill(threads[1], SIGUSR1);

    puts("Destroyed pool");

    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use casts, really. Get your interfaces right. Thread function *have to be* `void* (*)(void*)`, nothing else. Your program has undefined behavior. Also keep in mind that in C an empty parameter list is *not* a function that doesn't receive arguments but an unspecific number of arguments. Don't use that feature, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: You may also wish to take the advice from this [Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687985/pthread-exit-in-signal-handler) regarding usage of `pthread_exit` and signal handling.

Comment: Jens Gustedt thanks for the remarks but I don't see how they have anything to do with the question. Even changing things as per your suggestions doesn't change the behaviour of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

### You can't get there from here

pthread_exit() is not listed in the "signal safe funtions" of the signal(7) man page.
rewrite your code to have the pthread_exit call outside of the signal handler.

Comment: I will look into it. However the weird thing is that if I use a normal semaphore the thing works fine (working code snippet attached to question).

Comment: @Pithikos It isn't all that weird since the code has many unsafe operations and race conditions - so you might just be out of luck in one case vs another. In particular with your version using a pthread_mutex, you are exiting one thread while it holds a mutex, so who knows what'll go on with the other thread when it calls pthread_exit() in an unsafe way (in a signal handler). Hanging due to using printf() in a signal handler is'n't unheard of either. (Note also that threads arn't disposed of when they end unless you either call pthread_join() on them, or create them as detached threads).

Answer (score 0):

**So the issue seemed to be a deadlock!**

The problem is that each thread is waiting inside the `bsem_wait` of the binary semaphore in different locations:

```
void bsem_wait(bsem_t *bsem) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bsem->mutex); // THREAD 2 BLOCKED HERE
    while (bsem->v != 1) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&bsem->cond, &bsem->mutex); // THREAD 1 WAITING HERE
    }
    bsem->v = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bsem->mutex);
}
```

*Thread 1* in this case is the fastest thread. *Thread 2* is the slower one. When I run the signal to kill a thread, the waiting thread unblocks and exits as expected. The problem is that it **never unlocks the mutex**. So the blocked thread (2) remains blocked forever. For some reason, the thread won't be terminated because it is waiting on the mutex.

Just adding an unblock before exiting, solves the issue:

```
void thread_exit(){
    printf("%u: pthread_exit()\n", (int)pthread_self());
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); //  NEW CODE
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This ofcourse is a hack to demonstrate what is happening and shouldn't be used. I am going to follow Jasen's advice and get rid of the signal handler all together and solve it some other way. Namely I have to assure that the thread goes through the whole `bsem_wait`!